# AWS: KMSClient vs KMSClientBuilder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

In the AWS SDK https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/kms/package-summary.html the KMS has two different types of clients. A regular client and a client builder. What is the purpose of them both? When do you choose one over the other?

I'm trying to implement envelope encryption using KMS. I want to be able to hit the KMS endpoint and encrypt the payload. Which client library should I be using?

Comment: The client builder is used to build the client

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary no I get that.. but what's the difference between the two? One build the client and the other one is just a regular client?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary

How I would build out the kmsClient

`AwsBasicCredentials awsCredentials = 
                AwsBasicCredentials.create(keyManagementService.getUserKey(), keyManagementService.getSecretKey());

         kmsClient = KmsClient.builder()
                .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCredentials))
                .region(Region.EU_WEST_2)
                .endpointOverride(keyManagementService.getKmsUri())
               .build();`

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary and then the client builder: 

`AwsBasicCredentials awsCredentials =
                AwsBasicCredentials.create(keyManagementService.getUserKey(), keyManagementService.getSecretKey());

         kmsClientBuilder.credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCredentials))
                .region(Region.EU_WEST_2)
                .endpointOverride(keyManagementService.getKmsUri())
                .build();`

Kind of on second thought.. they're essentially doing the same thing? They act very similar?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary ace man. Thanks for that. I will infact by you a coffee through your bio.

Can I ask another question around KMS? If I want to hit the KMS endpoint is this the correct solution? Like this:  `.endpointOverride(https://kms.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com)`,  < because my instance is in London and it's region is this. In your answer you've specified the http client also?

When I then use the sign() function of my client, will it automatically hit this endpoint and use the defined configuration? Or how does it work? The documentation is a bit hard to come by around this kind of stuff.

Comment: No worries - that's scope for another question but no, the endpoint override is for calling things like Localstack i.e. emulations of AWS. Just use `.region` to set the region to `eu-west-2` & the SDK will configure the endpoints automatically. You also don't need HTTP client customisation - the default `.region` and `.credentials` will get your job sorted. If you don't know if you need specific customisation regarding AWS clients, it means that you don't need it most of the time :)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary thanks so much man. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one client type: `KmsClient`.

It can be created in 2 ways:

1. Using the `KmsClientBuilder` returned by `KmsClient.builder()` to modify properties and ultimately do `.Build` for your customised version of the client - this `KmsClientBuilder` is an instance of `DefaultKmsClientBuilder`, which is currently the only class that implements the client builder interface.
2. Using the `KmsClient` returned by `KmsClient.create()`, which is exactly the equivalent (and a shortcut) to `new DefaultKmsClientBuilder().build()` - this method returns a client set up with the region & credentials already loaded from the respective default provider chain, for applications that don't require further customisation.

This is how the above looks like in code:

```java
final KmsClient defaultKmsClient = KmsClient.create();
final KmsClient alsoDefaultKmsClientButLonger = KmsClient.builder().build();
final KmsClient customisedKmsClient = KmsClient.builder()
        .region(...)
        .credentialsProvider(...)
        .httpClient(...)
        .endpointOverride(...)
        ...
```

In conclusion, **use `KmsClient.create()` if you do not require a particular configuration**, as the default region and creds should be sufficient in most cases.

If not, then customise it via an instance of the builder (which can only be accessed via the `KmsClient.builder()` method since `KmsClientBuilder` is an interface).

**They are not 'different'.**

The builder ultimately is what creates the client.